# Adding children to StackLayout inside for loop causes this error "Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete." in Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

```
foreach (var equipment in EquipmentCollection)
{
  var control = new EquipmentControl(equipment);               
  MyStackLayout.Children.Add(control);               
}
```

I am getting this error only in UWP but not in Android. Even in UWP if the list size is small it is working fine.

I have tried few work arounds but still I couldn't able to make it work.

Since there is no UpdateLayout() method for xamarin-forms controls so I tried to use custom renderer for stacklayout and raised a child added event and called UpdateLayout() inside it but still got the crash.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomStackLayout), typeof(CustomStackLayoutRenderer))]
namespace FO4.UWP.Controls
{
    public class CustomStackLayoutRenderer : ViewRenderer<StackLayout, StackPanel>
    {
        StackPanel stkPanel; 
        
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
                                      
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                CustomStackLayout stkLayout = (CustomStackLayout)e.NewElement;
                stkLayout.ChildAdded += StkLayout_ChildAdded;                

            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                CustomStackLayout stkLayout = (CustomStackLayout)e.OldElement;
                stkLayout.ChildAdded -= StkLayout_ChildAdded;                
            }

        }

        private void StkLayout_ChildAdded(object sender, ElementEventArgs e)
        {           
            this.UpdateLayout();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you could create a StackLayout (or whatever container) in memory, assign the children to it, and **then** attach it to the visual tree, so that the layout logic is only called once the controls have been added

Answer (score 0):

I develop in Xamarin Forms but I don't target UWP.
Here some suggestions that will maybe help you:

1. For this kind of need, it is more frequent to use DataBinding through BindableLayout.ItemTemplate and Bindable.ItemsSource like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts#populate-a-bindable-layout-with-data.
2. If you don't want to use these mechanism, maybe you can try to use the BatchBegin() and BatchCompleted() method before and after your Loop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.batchbegin?view=xamarin-forms

The use of a renderer shoud not be required in my opinion...